# Passing dictionary<k,v> from 1 form to another form if certain criteria is met

Tags: c#, dictionary, properties

I am pretty new at c# so please be patient. This is most likely design problem. I want to pass value of dictionary from one form to the other when certain criteria is met since i load everything on my 1st form.

My app is basically load csv files containing recipes and print them on excel's template which later on will be printed out on paper. I have 2 forms in wpf. Where the 1st form read csv files,  display data in gridview method and saved the data in dictionary for later use. 2nd form get called when i double click on the gridview's cell.

2nd form will then dynamically create labels, textboxes and load csv file containing excel cell's placements depended on the ID of selected product. A little bit out of topic, it will then print out the excel using EPPLUS reference library.

Here's an example of my data csv file:

```
ID,Product's Type, Product's Name, Ingredient01, Ingredient01 Qty
A0101,SoftCake,Cheese Cake, Flour, 100g
A0201,CupCake,Blueberry Cupcake, Blueberries, 50g
A0202,CupCake,Chocolate Cupcake, Chocolate, 50g
```

here's my csv file for formatted cell:

```
Index, Product's Name, Ingredients01, Ingredients01 Qty
First Page,A21:D21, K20, J20
Second Page,A48:D48, K68, J68
```

This is just an example but the real data has a lot more ingredients

here's the code so far

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
Form2 f2;

public Dictionary<string, string[]> recipeDict;
private Dictionary<string, string[]> formattedCell; //excel format

public Dictionary<string, string[]> FormattedCell;
//property of the first form
public Form1()
        {
            this.AutoSize = true;
            InitializeComponent();

            recipeDict = File
                .ReadAllLines(recipePath)
                .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                .GroupBy(arr => arr[0])
                .ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key, gr => gr
                 .SelectMany(s => new string[] {s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5], s[6], s[7] }).ToArray());

            FormattedCell = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
            FormattedCell = formattedCell;
         }
}

private void DataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     f2 = new Form2();
     char tempID;
     //debugging
     Console.WriteLine(tempID = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()[0]);

     if(tempID == "A")
    {
       formattedCell = File
         .ReadAllLines(excelTemplatePath)
         .Select(line => line.Split(','))
         .GroupBy(arr => arr[0])
         .ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key, gr => gr
         .SelectMany(s => new string[] {s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5], s[6], s[7] }).ToArray());


     }
      f2.ShowDialog();
}


//2nd form
public partial class Form2: Form
{
      string[] firstPageCells, secondPageCell;
      Form1 f1;

//property
public Form2()
{
     f1 = new Form1();
     InitializeCellsArray();
}
private void InitializeCellsArray()
        {
            var valueLength = f1.FormattedCell.Max(t => t.Value.Length);
            //initialize every cellsArray
            firstPageCells = new string[valueLength];
            secondPageCells = new string[valueLength];


            //insert arrays from dictionary list
            f1.FormattedCell.TryGetValue("First Page", out firstPageCells);
            f1.FormattedCell.TryGetValue("Second Page", out secondPageCells);
}
}
```

However, f1.FormattedCell returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FormattedCell as a public variable of f1 is null because in the constructor you do this:

```
        FormattedCell = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
        FormattedCell = formattedCell;
```

formattedCell (with a lowercase f) is independent of FormattedCell (with an uppercase F). You init FormattedCell with a new Dictionary then immediately set it to equal formattedCell which is null at the time. Trying then to use FormattedCell will result in a null ref error. Later you do set formattedCell (with a lowercase f) to something valid but changing formattedCell so it points to something valid won't change what FormattedCell points to, which will remain null.

Essentially it works like this when the constructor is done running:

```
formattedCell -> null  //points to null because the member is not set
FormattedCell -> null //pound to null because the last line of the constructor "points it to whatever formattedCell points to"
```

Assignment is c# doesn't work like this:

```
FormattedCell -> formattedCell -> null
```

Which means when you later point formattedCell to something, FormattedCell is still left pointing at null:

```
formattedCell -> (a dictionary)
FormattedCell -> null
```

I'm guessing you intended for FormattedCell to be a public property that referenced the private variable formattedCell:

```
public ... FormattedCell {
  get { return formattedCell; }
  set { formattedCell = value }
}
```

Doing things shorthand would make things easier. I suggest you change things at the top of the file, removing the private variable `formattedCell` entirely (as it will only cause another similar confusion) and turn FormattedCell into a public property:

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
  Form2 f2;//you can remove this as a class wide variable and just instantiate it locally in the double click because you don't reuse it

    public Dictionary<string, string[]> RecipeDict {get; set;} //make it a property by putting a get/set, capitalise the firt letter of public members

    //remove formttedCell

    public Dictionary<string, string[]> FormattedCell {get;set}
```

Change your code references to find "formattedCell" replace with "FormattedCell "

Also consider making Form1 a parameter to your constructor of Form2 so that instead of Form2 having to make its own instance of Form1, it can just refer to an existing instance without needing to re read files all over again:

```
public Form2(Form1 f) //form2's constructor


new Form2(this).ShowDialog(); //inside form1, open a new form2 but use the existing form1
```

I recommend you do this because it is your mouse click that reads and populates the FormattedCell - if your form2 makes a new form1, that Form1 won't have experienced the mouse click that read the file so FormattedCell in the new form will still be null

If you won't ultimately need form2 to read other things about Form1 or set things on Form1, don't give form2 a reference to Form1. Instead give form2 the dictionary itself, and get rid of the class wide FormattedCells variable from Form1:

```
private void DataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
       var fmt = File
         .ReadAllLines(excelTemplatePath)
         .Select(line => line.Split(','))
         .GroupBy(arr => arr[0])
         .ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key, gr => gr
         .SelectMany(s => new string[] {s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5], s[6], s[7] }).ToArray());

        new f2(fmt).Show(); //if you use Show instead of ShowDialog you can have 2 recipes open at the same time
}




//remember to make your form2 constructor take a Dictionary
public Form2(Dictionary<string, string[]> d)
```

Ultimately this is all a great learning exercise - don't be tempted to make everything a class wide variable/property. Keep things scoped to as low down as you can get away with. Only make thing class wide if several things will reuse them otherwise you'll get into a situation where the user or developer has done B before A and things aren't set up right in the class wide variables

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing `FormattedCell` with a new dictionary and then promptly overwriting it with `null`:

```
FormattedCell = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
FormattedCell = formattedCell;
```

Reference types in C# have a value of `null` if you don't assign anything to them, and you didn't initialize `formattedCell` in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Statement **FormattedCell = formattedCell;**  is in Form1 constructor so it initializes null, because it is (formattedCell) null.

you may  have to assign  FormattedCell = formattedCell again in **DataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick()** event.

and also, **char tempID;** is char so you can't compare it with hardcore string **"A"**

```
DataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick()
{
     if(tempID == 'A')
      {
       //Your code
       FormattedCell = formattedCell;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this lines please:

> //property public Form2() {
>        f1 = new Form1();
>        InitializeCellsArray(); }

You are creating a new instance of Form1 which has no data associated. For example, if your Form1 name is "MyForm" you should have something like:

```
f1 = MyForm
```